# Detect Tweet deletion with Twitter Streaming API

Tags: twitter, twitter-streaming-api

The Twitter Streaming API can be used to detect a phrase using the following query:
http://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json?track=phrase

However, the same query doesn't seem to detect when the tweet is deleted. Is there a way to do that with the API?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api_concepts), you're supposed to get deletions in the stream, they should look like this:

```
{"delete":{"status":{"id":1234,"id_str":"1234","user_id":3,"user_id_str":"3"}}}
```

UPDATE: I did a few tests to see what was going on.  First, I tried the filter URL with a track parameter, just like you are trying, and confirmed the same behavior that you are seeing.  Then I tried a URL with a 'follow' setting instead, like so:

```
http://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json\?follow\=1160471
```

When I try that, I get both tweets and their deletion messages.  It's hard to know for certain obviously without asking Twitter, but I wonder if you just don't get deletions at all when using a track parameter, or if it's another issue along those lines.

Comment: Read the same docs but unfortunately it doesn't work with the stream syntax I provided. Thinking maybe I'm not using the correct query/url.

Comment: Just wondering, are you waiting for a random deletion, or are you explicitly deleting a tweet, and then not seeing it come across via the API?

Comment: I haven't played with the streaming API enough, but I wonder if you're just not getting the deletion since there's no explicit guarantee at all that you will get particular tweets.

Comment: I'll try a few more things but guessing the delete should come through the same way the tweets do (they appear every time I post).

Comment: Hey I tried a couple experiments, and added the results above.